# How to add Cookies banner in Sitecore?

Tags: cookies

I would like to add cookies banner in Sitecore 9.1 version. I am using SXA 1.8. I have already added the Privacy warning in our site and would like to add cookies banner along with confirm , reject and manage button.

I have checked the Sitecore site there they are using cookies consent. I would like to add as its in our site.

[image]

Comment: There are many ways to add cookie consent to your Sitecore site. Just adding a cookie warning does not change what cookies are used on the site, it just lets the user know that cookies are in use. A cookie consent implementation would require custom code or maybe an integration with something like onetrust. The question is too open ended for SSE.

Answer (score 2):

You can go through the below link - https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/sxa/93/sitecore-experience-accelerator/add-a-cookie-warning-message-to-your-site.html

If you want to be compliant with General Data Protection Regulation (GDPR) and ePrivacy, you must inform your users about collection and sharing of personal information. SXA lets you inform visitors that your site uses cookies. You can customize the message, select the warning type, and exclude pages from having cookie warnings.

To add a cookie warning to your pages:

1. In the Content Editor, navigate to `sitecore/Content/<tenant>/<site>/Settings/Privacy Warning`.
2. In the Privacy Warning Content section, fill in the following fields:

[image]

Comment: The link you have added is not pointing to SXA version 1.8 and there is no link available for 1.8. But I have checked that the file is available in SXA 1.8 and I think it should work

Comment: Yeah, it has the same path in SXA 1.8.